# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, cassandra

While saving Data to cassandra database i.e

Line :

```
com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(metricsRDD)
    .writerBuilder("a2imetrics", "performance_data_stage", 
    mapToRow(PerfMetricsTable.class)).saveToCassandra();
```

On this line i am hitting the exception

My Pom.xml is as :

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
    <scala.main.version>2.11</scala.main.version>
    <spark.version>2.3.0</spark.version>
    <scalatest.version>3.0.0</scalatest.version>
    <connector.version>2.3.0</connector.version>
    <cassandra.version>3.0</cassandra.version>
    <org.apache.spark.spark-core.version>2.3.0</org.apache.spark.spark-core.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

</properties>

<!-- Please make sure that following dependencies have versions corresponding 
    to the ones in your cluster. Note that spark-cassandra-connector should be 
    provided with '&#45;&#45;packages' flag to spark-submit command. -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.main.version}</artifactId> 
        <version>${spark.version}</version> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.main.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
        <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.main.version}</artifactId> 
        <version>${spark.version}</version> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_${scala.main.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${connector.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.17.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test Dependencies <dependency> <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-embedded_${scala.main.version}</artifactId> 
        <version>${connector.version}</version> <scope>test</scope> <exclusions> 
        <exclusion> <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId> <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId> 
        </exclusion> </exclusions> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId> 
        <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.main.version}</artifactId> <version>${scalatest.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>junit</groupId> <artifactId>junit</artifactId> 
        <version>${junit.version}</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId> <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId> 
        <version>${cassandra.version}</version> <scope>test</scope> <exclusions> -->
    <!-- Excluded to allow for Cassandra to run embedded <exclusion> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId> </exclusion> </exclusions> </dependency> 
        Force Guava 18 on Test CP, Required for Cassandra -->



</dependencies>
<!-- <build> <plugins> <plugin> <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId> <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>3.2.2</version> <executions> <execution> <phase>process-sources</phase> 
    <goals> <goal>compile</goal> <goal>testCompile</goal> </goals> <configuration> 
    <mainSourceDir>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/../scala</mainSourceDir> 
    </configuration> </execution> </executions> </plugin> <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId> <version>2.4.3</version> <executions> 
    <execution> <phase>package</phase> <goals> <goal>shade</goal> </goals> <configuration> 
    </configuration> </execution> </executions> </plugin> -->
<!-- Instructions from http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin -->
<!-- disable surefire -->
<!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>2.7</version> <configuration> <skipTests>true</skipTests> </configuration> 
    </plugin> -->
<!-- enable scalatest -->
<!--<plugin> <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId> <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>1.0</version> <configuration> <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory> 
    <junitxml>.</junitxml> <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports> </configuration> 
    <executions> <execution> <id>test</id> <goals> <goal>test</goal> </goals> 
    </execution> </executions> </plugin> </plugins> </build> -->
```

```
<!-- <dependencies> <dependency> <groupId>commons-logging</groupId> <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId> 
    <version>1.1.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId> <version>2.3.0</version> 
    </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId> 
    <version>2.2.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>junit</groupId> 
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId> <version>3.8.1</version> <scope>test</scope> 
    </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId> 
    <version>2.3.1</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId> <version>2.2.1</version> </dependency> 
    <dependency> <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId> <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId> 
    <version>3.5.0</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId> 
    <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId> <version>0.11.0</version> </dependency> 
    <dependency> <groupId>log4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j</artifactId> <version>1.2.17</version> 
    </dependency> </dependencies> <properties> <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding> 
    <org.apache.spark.spark-core.version>2.2.1</org.apache.spark.spark-core.version> 
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source> <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target> 
    </properties> </project> -->
```

Comment: Well ,i got the answer for this, may be it will help someone, So it was version problem, i used 2.3.0 instead of 2.3.2 , wherever applicable ..it worked.Previously was using spark 2.2 version and sql -2.3.0, because of it i was getting exception.